# How to extract a word from a string and assign it to a variable in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-3.7

Okay so I'm trying to creating this basic bot that answers some questions that I ask it using Python 3.7.

I needed to create a system that when I ask it a meaning of a word, it replies with the meaning of that word. To do this, I used the module called PyDictionary.

Now lets say I ask:

"What is the meaning of dictionary"

I want to extract the word "dictionary" and put it inside a variable then put that variable through some code that will figure out the meaning to that word.

How can I extract the word "dictionary" so I can put it into a variable?

I haven't tried any specific solutions to this, I can seem to figure out the logic to this since I'm a newbie to Python.

```
#This will be the module I'm importing
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
dictionary=PyDictionary()

#This line of code will be used to get the meaning:
print (dictionary.meaning("test"))

#The string "text" will be replaced with a variable containing the extracted word.
```

The expected result should be that:

When someone types:

"What is the meaning of text"

"text" gets extracted and be put into a variable, then I can assign that variable to another line of code to get the meaning.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the split funktion to split your sentence into a list of words.

```
a="this is an example sentence"
a=a.split()
print(a)
```

And then extract just the last word:

```
last_word=a[-1] #assigning the first element from behind to a variable
```

To pass this variable to your dictionary module.

Comment: Just tried this out and it worked perfectly! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

If your word will always be a the end of the line, just use `str.split` and take the last result:

```
phrase = input()
words = phrase.split()
if len(words) > 0:
    lookup = words[-1]
    print (dictionary.meaning(lookup))
```

Presumably the phrase might also have a `?` at the end, so maybe you want to do something like:

```
lookup.rstrip('?')
```

Comment: Actually, I figured it out lmao. I want to implement it using the elif statement, any idea on how I could do that?